Aliens/creatures having sex with humans and killing them
Is there any movie in which aliens are having sex with people and killing them by sex, like with semen coming out of women's mouth? I just saw that scene but don't know any more about it. I don't know if they were creatures or aliens and I watched that movie many years ago.
Some clips I know: A wooden bar or maybe house outside of the city and some people are stuck because of some aliens outside of the wooden bar. People are watching outside and they see some creatures having sex with each other.
Also I watched a scene where a woman falls from a window, then suddenly that creature came from somewhere and had sex with her. That creature had sex so much that semen came out of the woman and she died (maybe). It was night when that creature killed the woman.
I only know this information. I want to know the movie's name.

I can only guess: The Project Greenlight horror film Feast from 2005 is about a group of people stuck in a bar at night and being attacked by monsters; in one scene they look outside and see the monsters having sex, and in another, as specified by IMDb's parental guide (WARNING - GRAPHIC DETAILS):

A creature forces itself onto a woman, making her perform forced oral sex on it (it is not graphically seen, we see the creature thrusting above the woman's head); when it finishes the woman spits up a lot of sperm-like liquid.

Here's the trailer:




Good call on the description ... Not much given from the OP.

Liquid Sky - See if this sound right:

The crew arrives at Margaret's apartment for the fashion shoot. During the shoot Margaret is taunted by Jimmy, so she agrees to give him oral sex, knowing it will kill him. Jimmy dies and the body evaporates as Paul's had. Adrian perversely encourages Margaret to have sex with her, and Adrian also dies. A vengeful Margaret applies new make-up, deserts the shocked crew and goes to a downtown nightclub. There she reconnects with Vincent, who previously raped her. Back at her apartment she seduces him, ensuring his death. Katherine arrives at the nightclub asking after Paul's dealer, Adrian.
Johann reveals that the alien is extracting the endorphins produced by the brain when an orgasm occurs — apparently a fatal operation. Johann resumes observation of Margaret's apartment and sees she is in mortal danger so goes to help her. He tells Margaret she survived because she never experienced an orgasm. Seeing the alien craft leaving, Margaret stabs Johann in the back and injects herself with heroin to induce a wild autoerotic orgasm to ensure the aliens take her with them. Sylvia and Katherine arrive at the apartment together and reach the penthouse in time to see Margaret vaporized by the aliens.


Could you provide source of the plot description?

Although it's been a while since I've seen it, IIRC other than 'aliens' and 'fellatio', nothing in the OP's description fits Liquid Sky.

It is POSSIBLE you are describing an installment in the Species series. In that continuity, there is a human-alien hybrid that escapes from captivity, (and euthanasia), and becomes determined to mate with a human to produce an offspring. She kills people who either don't perform or who she sees as a threat.
However, I have not seen all the films, so the component of there being a forceful element with the woman having sex after falling does not ring a bell with me.

Maybe this one its called Decoys.

Luke and Roger are just another couple of college guys trying to lose their virginity. But when Luke sees something unusual, he begins to suspect that the girls on campus aren't exactly human.




